# Storing each character of a string into an array (c++)

Tags: c++, c-strings

i want to make sure im reading this code properly

```
const int SIZE = 40;
char firstString[SIZE], secondString[SIZE];
```

is this making 2 char variables (called firstString and secondString) and storing those characters that are in "firstString" and "secondString" into an array (once the user enters something that gets stored into them)? Is this name of the arrays the same as the variable name? (firstString and secondString)?

Comment: thanks guys. I would vote you both up but i only have 14 rep. I'm not sure why somebody voted my question down. I was clear with my question and provided the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the variables `firstString`, `secondString` ARE arrays of `char` of size 40.

```
char firstString[SIZE], secondString[SIZE];
```

only *defines* these arrays, that is, announces to the compiler their names and causes it to allocate memory for them, that is, two chunks of 40 `char`s. It does not store anything in them.

AFTER this declaration (and in the same block), you can store user input in them (in C, strings are arrays of `char`s).

Note that "variables" `firstString`, `secondString` cannot exist simultaneously with these arrays: if they have been declared in the same block it will cause a compile error; if they have been declared in an outer block their names will be hidden by this declaration and their values will have nothing to do with these arrays. No copying will happen.

Answer (score 0):

That code declares a constant `int` named `SIZE`, then declares two character arrays of size `SIZE`.  No string copying or other initialization is performed.